# How to revert back to expo after ejecting from expo?

Tags: expo, eas, expo-eas, expo-dev-client

I have ejected my expo react native app from expo by running,

```
npx expo run:android
```

but I want to revert back to expo to create a development build

```
eas build --profile development --platform android
```

but the problem is I don't have a git commit before ejecting the app what can I do?

Comment: you can still create a development build with `eas build`, even with the `android` directory (EAS Build works great with any React Native app). if you'd like EAS Build to run `prebuild` for you, feel free to just delete the `android` directory in your project, or add it to `.gitignore`. https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/prebuild/